# Why is my render blotchy and how do I get rid of it?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, noise-reduction, denoise

So I have this scene I'm trying to render and I noticed no matter how many samples I use, I can't get rid of the blotches on it. I used 1200 samples in this render. I'm using cycles. This took 4-ish hrs to render. The .blend is over the 25MB limit pastall.org allows, if you need the file, is there a different site I can use?

.blender and render: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ie3EG59ds0gOR82jqt8WL5V4yv3dJogf?usp=sharing

[image: ss to save space]
[image: render settings]

Comment: By blotches do you mean grain? What exactly do you mean by blotches? Can you circle specific places in the image to look at. You can zip and upload the file to google drive. ALSO please do File > External Data > Pack Resources so the image files are zipped up too (if there are any)

Comment: @Gunt.r ok ill do that tomorrow, and on the top and bottom (ceiling, floor) I'm talking about all those white smudges on the left and right sides, it should be completely smooth/reflective with the texture. Also something I forgot to add is when I render it slows down blender to the point where it lags when I move the render window.

Comment: alright ill have to take a look at the blend file. yep it is normal to slow blender down alot when you render

Comment: it looks like it's the effect of the Denoise, have you tried to disable it?

Comment: @Gunt.r yeah im used to it being a little slower, but not as slow/laggy as it makes it now.  And heres the files: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1ie3EG59ds0gOR82jqt8WL5V4yv3dJogf?usp=sharing

Comment: @moonboots is there a better way to denoise it than the built-in denoise?

Comment: there are several denoisers, I'm afraid you'll get the same result, but you need to give a try, is it your problem here?

Comment: After rendering its still noisy and stuff, just no blotches because its not denoising it,

Comment: Yes so your problem came from the denoise which can work bad with some images, I'm not sure you can fix it, so maybe try to increase the sampling

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135832/discussion-between-todahmoon-and-moonboots).